# ipywidgets to allow interactive filtering via a function are not displaying or updating the df

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Given a dataframe (allCol) containing metadata information for a database:

- Catalog
- Table Name (TabName)
- Column Name (ColName)
- Description

use ipywidgets to create filters that allow an end user to interact with the df directly via dropdown filters.

The code listed below works 100% if all the contents from display_widgets() is run in its own cell, or if each variable is declared globally first. I would like the code to be inside a function because my end goal is to mutate the allCol df by updating its descriptions and re-displaying it by calling the display_widgets() function. Am I missing something? Can these widgets be embedded in a function? Any help is appreciated thanks! (code is adapted from [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/bring-your-jupyter-notebook-to-life-with-interactive-widgets-bc12e03f0916) )

Ex// allCol shape:

| Catalog | TabName | ColName | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Movies | HorrorMovies | MovieTitle | Gives the title of the movie |
| Movies | HorrorMovies | Actors | Gives a list of starring actors in the movie |
| Movies | HorrorMovies | RunTime | Gives the total runtime of the movie in minutes |
| Movies | ActionMovies | MovieTitle | Gives the title of the movie |
| Movies | ActionMovies | Actors | Gives a list of starring actors in the movie |
| Movies | ActionMovies | RunTime | Gives the total runtime of the movie in minutes |
| Songs | Country | SongTitle | Gives the title of the song |
| Songs | Country | Singer | Gives a list of starring singers of the song |
| Songs | Country | RunTime | Gives the total runtime of the song in minutes |

```
def common_filtering(table, catalog, description):
    filtered_output.clear_output()
    if not description: description = None
    
    if (table == ALL) & (catalog == ALL):
        common_filter = allCol
        tab_opts = unique_sorted_values_plus_ALL(common_filter['TabName'])
        dropdown_table.options = tab_opts
    
    elif (catalog == ALL):
        common_filter = allCol[allCol.TabName == table]
        tab_opts = unique_sorted_values_plus_ALL(allCol['TabName'])
        dropdown_table.options = tab_opts
        
    elif (table == ALL):
        common_filter = allCol[allCol.Catalog == catalog]
        tab_opts = unique_sorted_values_plus_ALL(common_filter['TabName'])
        dropdown_table.options = tab_opts
    
    else:
        common_filter = allCol[(allCol.TabName == table) & 
                               (allCol.Catalog == catalog)]
        tab_opts = unique_sorted_values_plus_ALL(allCol[allCol['Catalog'] == catalog]['TabName'])
        dropdown_table.options = tab_opts
    
    with filtered_output:
        display(common_filter.style.applymap(lambda x: highlight_descr_keyword(x, description)
                                                       ,subset = ['Description']))

def unique_sorted_values_plus_ALL(array):
    ALL = 'ALL'
    unique = array.unique().tolist()
    unique.sort()
    unique.insert(0, ALL)
    return unique

def highlight_descr_keyword(value, comparison):
    if isinstance(value, str) and isinstance(comparison, str):
        if comparison in value:
            return 'color: red'
        else:
            return 'color: black'
    else:
        return 'color: black'

def dropdown_table_eventhandler(change):
    common_filtering(change.new, dropdown_catalog.value, text_description)
    
def dropdown_catalog_eventhandler(change):
    common_filtering(dropdown_table.value, change.new, text_description)
    
def text_description_eventhandler(change):
    common_filtering(dropdown_table.value, dropdown_catalog.value, change.new)

def display_widgets(allCol):
    # Creates the output window for user interaction
    filtered_output = widgets.Output()

    # Sets the options for a table and catalog filter dropdown menu
    tab_opts = unique_sorted_values_plus_ALL(allCol.TabName)
    cata_opts = unique_sorted_values_plus_ALL(allCol.Catalog)

    # Creates the dropdown filter objects in the output
    dropdown_catalog = widgets.Dropdown(options = cata_opts, description = 'Catalogs: ')
    dropdown_table   = widgets.Dropdown(options = tab_opts,description = 'Table: ')
    text_description = widgets.Text(placeholder='Type something...'
                                   ,description='Descriptions:')

    # Sets up observations on the created filtration objects 
    dropdown_table.observe(dropdown_table_eventhandler, names='value')
    dropdown_catalog.observe(dropdown_catalog_eventhandler, names='value')
    text_description.observe(text_description_eventhandler, names='value')

    # Sets the layout of the output
    item_layout = widgets.Layout(margin='0 0 50px 0')

    # Formats the output object
    input_widgets = widgets.HBox([dropdown_catalog
                                 ,dropdown_table
                                 ,text_description]
                                 ,layout = item_layout)

    # Creates an interactive dashboard and displays it in the bottom cell of the notebook
    dashboard = widgets.VBox([input_widgets, filtered_output])
    display(dashboard)
```